# how to alter an awk variable with sed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

i have a bash command that produces a list of files for which i need to alter the filename.
so i was thinking of using something like this:

```
mycommand | awk {mv $1 altered$1}
```

the problem is that the second $1 should be altered replacing with sed some regular expressions. 
how can i apply sed to the second parameter?

i tried with $() and |, but it does not work.

I also tried

```
awk '{print $1 sed "s/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g" <<< $1}'
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

Comment: Have you considered looping through the returned list of filenames from your command and modifying them with `sed`? `for filename in $(mycommand); do mv $filename $(sed "s/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g" <<< $filename); done`.

Comment: Note that a `for filename in $(mycommand)` will fail if any file name contains whitespace.  A `while` loop can avoid that.

Comment: recall that `awk` has the `sub()` and `gsub()` functions and that they can do most of what `sed's 's/str/repl/'` can do. You may need to do several `[g]sub(/regex/,"repl","str")` operations to get what you need. Good luck.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code and approach in general all I can suggest is that you read some kind of intro to shell scripting before trying to write code. Ditto for awk.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` is not an awk command.  You need shell.  Try:

```
mycommand | while IFS= read -r f; do mv "$f" "${f//[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_}"; done
```

This assumes that the file names are newline-separated.  This is OK unless a file name contains a newline as part of its name.  For better reliability, `mycommand` and the while loop should be modified to use NUL as the separator.

How it works:

- `while IFS= read -r f; do`

  This starts a loop that reads each line, in turn, into variable `f`.

  `IFS=` tells the shell to keep the leading or trailing whitespace on a line.  If `mycommand` produces superfluous leading or trailing whitespace, then remove this.

  `-r` tells the shell to keep backslashes in the input just as they are.
- `mv "$f" "${f//[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_}"`

  This renames the file.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Is subshell accepted by you? If yes, a simple way you can do as followed:

```
mv `mycommand | awk '{print $1}'` {altered$1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` (always installed in *Debian* based distros, via the *required* **util-linux** package):

```
rename 's/^/altered/' $(mycommand)
```